# how to limit a google map search result to a specific area

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

let's say that I need a car service in NYC , when I open the app and choose the service that I need I want the map to show markers in the map of that service just in NYC. 
the app now shows the service's markers ,but in the whole country not just in a specific area.

```
 final String selected2=spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

          ValueEventListener postlistener = new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                      Service service = snapshot.getValue(Service.class);
                      try{

                          if (service.getTypes().equals(selected2)) {
                              lat = service.getLat();
                              lon = service.getLon();
                              final LatLng point = new LatLng(lat, lon);


                              mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                      .position(point)
                                      .title(service.getNomservice())
                                      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                                      .snippet("Horaire d'ouverture:"+service.getTime())

                              );
```

Please help.

Comment: show your code and what you have tried to solve your issue

Comment: done , I only tried the part where I show all the markers of the selected service in the list

Comment: do you want to only show the markers in that region, or have the map zoomed into only that region?

Comment: I want the markers to appear only in the region zoomed in by the user

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds` to get a bounding box of the visible region of the map, then just don't add any services that have lat/lon outside of that bounding box.

Also, its probably not a good idea to use `Service` as the name for whatever service this app is meant to be providing, as `Service` is already used extensively by android.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I make this test  , this is what I wrote but it didn't work "if(mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.contains(point)" the point is actually a latlon variable .

Comment: look at the documentation (here)[https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion.html#latLngBounds], then make sure the coords are greater than the top left coordinate, and less than the lower right.